# Checkbox is always checked even not checked

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.4

I have a checkbox that is always checked no matter if I checked the box or not.

Here is how the checkbox is currently setup:

```
    <input class="classname" id="check"  value="1" <?php echo (($temp['test']) ? 'checked' : '');  ?> name="check" type="checkbox" />
```

Here is how the check box value is being captured:

```
     $check = $_POST['check'] ?? 0;
```

I also tried the following code as well:

```
      $check = (isset($_POST['check']) == '1' ? '1' : '0');
```

I tried the hidden field approach as well and it didn't work. Any ideas on why the checkbox is showing marked even though I removed the check.

Comment: When you say "showing marked", do you mean on page rerender or do you mean that the form processing (value of `$check`) is always positive?

Comment: What $temp['test'] and how is it related to $_POST['check']?

Answer (score 1):

I think Drussy might be onto something, where does $_POST['test'] come from?

Try this code:

```
$checked = isset($_POST['check']) ? 'checked' : '';

<input class="classname" id="check"  value="1" <?php echo $checked; ?> name="check" type="checkbox" />
```